# Using https when calling waitFor method setting up openstack nova server

Tags: php, https, openstack

I have the following PHP script (this is just the bottom half):

```
use Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException;

$server = $compute->server();

try {
     $response = $server->create(array(
        'name'   => 'My server',
        'image'  => $centos,
        'flavor' => $twoGbFlavor
     ));
} catch (BadResponseException $e) {
    // No! Something failed. Let's find out:
    printf("Request: %s\n\nResponse: %s", $e->getRequest(), $e->getResponse());
 }

use OpenCloud\Compute\Constants\ServerState;

$callback = function($server) {
    if (!empty($server->error)) {
    var_dump($server->error);
    exit;
    } else {
        echo sprintf(
            "Waiting on %s/%-12s %4s%%",
            $server->name(),
            $server->status(),
            isset($server->progress) ? $server->progress : 0
        );
    }
};

$server->waitFor(ServerState::ACTIVE, 600, $callback);
```

When I run it I receive the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 52: Empty reply from server [url] http://api.openstack.ecloud.co.uk:8774/v2/b7db5fe13c044b6e95bf5b766ae49393/servers/f5bf8951-f662-4940-904c-023b98b724c0' in /var/www/html/nutshell/openstack/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php:359
```

I have narrowed it down to a problem with the waitFor method using http instead https. However I am unable to work out how to get this method to use https or if there is a setting I can change to force all calls over https?

In addition I have tried running these commands using curl on the command line, outside of the script, and can confirm the https one works. So I just need to work out how to get the script call to use https.

Also, note the $server->create call above works fine and I would have just expected the waitFor to work in the same fashion (i.e. over https).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i think you should mention that you're using that sdk: https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created server with https, got response with server data. Server data contains self url and that url is most probably http.
"waitFor" is calling openstack for server data with that url. You can see this here: 
https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/working/lib/OpenCloud/Common/Resource/BaseResource.php (line 148)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me chaoss88. I was looking in that file but couldn't work out how it was setting it to http. Do you know how I would go about making the self url https?

Comment: You can't. It looks like that bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/designate/+bug/1490034

Comment: You can't try to force url creation by removing "!" at line 150. But it's not a good practice to solve this.

Comment: Cheers that worked and will have to do for now. Appreciated.